# How to save output (prediction) of the CNN model in the form of an image?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a folder named `Downloaded` which contain images on which prediction has to be made by the trained CNN model.

Below is the code for importing images:

```
import os
images = []

for filename in os.listdir("downloaded"):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join("downloaded", filename))
    img = img.resize((32, 32))
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    img = np.array(img) / 255
    images.append(img)
```

Now, the below code helps to make predictions on these images:

```
predictions = model.predict(images)
```

Finally, the predictions are shown in the form of an image and a graph, for each image.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(9, 2, figsize=(10, 25))
axs = axs.ravel()
for i in range(18):
    if i%2 == 0:
        axs[i].axis('off')
        axs[i].imshow(images[i // 2])
        axs[i].set_title("Prediction: %s" % id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])

    else:
        axs[i].bar(np.arange(65), predictions[i // 2])
        axs[i].set_ylabel("Softmax")
        axs[i].set_xlabel("Labels")

plt.show()
```

I want to save this output in the form of image.

For that, I use the below code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(9, 2, figsize=(10, 25))
axs = axs.ravel()
for i in range(18):
    if i%2 == 0:
        axs[i].axis('off')
        axs[i].imshow(images[i // 2])
        axs[i].set_title("Prediction: %s" % id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])
        plt.imsave('"Prediction: %s" % id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])]',axs[i])

    else:
        axs[i].bar(np.arange(65), predictions[i // 2])
        axs[i].set_ylabel("Softmax")
        axs[i].set_xlabel("Labels")


plt.show()
```

But, comes up with the below error:

```
AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Could you please tell how to save this output in the for of images?

PS: Below is what `images` contain:

> Out[94]:
>
> [array([[[1.        , 0.85882353, 0.85882353],
>            [1.        , 0.04313725, 0.03921569],
>            [1.        , 0.04313725, 0.03921569],
>            ...,
>            [1.        , 0.04313725, 0.03921569],
>            [1.        , 0.03529412, 0.03137255],
>            [1.        , 0.76862745, 0.76470588]],
>
> ```
>     [[1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
>      [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
>      [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
>      ...,
>      [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
>      [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
>      [1.        , 0.        , 0.        ]],...................
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the array as image, you need to provide the array to `imsave`

```
plt.imsave('filename.png', images[i // 2])
```

If you want to save the matplotlib figure with the imshow plot in it to a file you should use `savefig`.

```
fig.savefig("filename.png")
```

Comment: Thanks. I can save my output using your second alternative. Although, if I have to save each image separately with prediction, then what I need to do? The first answer only saved the image but no prediction and graph.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the images using the below code:

```
for i in range(len(images)*2):
        finalPrediction.append(id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])
        plt.imsave(('testo/ {}.jpg'.format(str(i // 2)+id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])),images[i // 2])
```