# How to save prediction result of the CNN model in the image format?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, keras

I have been working with a CNN in Keras and I want to save the predictions as png images. This is my code to create the model and run the prediction:

```
 history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
        epochs=epochs,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=valid_steps)

    pred= model.predict(X_test)
```

I used following code based on below link and the pred folder remains empty. ([How to save output (prediction) of the CNN model in the form of an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52620222/how-to-save-output-prediction-of-the-cnn-model-in-the-form-of-an-image))

```
images = []
for i in range(len(images)*2):
        pred.append(id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])
        plt.imsave(('pred/ {}.png'.format(str(i // 2)+id_to_name[np.argmax(predictions[i // 2])])),images[i // 2])
```

Could you please tell how to save the model.predict predictions in the form of png images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your images have the format:

```
(batch_size, height, width, channels)
```

You can use [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/save_img)

```
import tensorflow as tf

images = tf.random.uniform((4, 224, 224, 3))

for i, image in enumerate(images, 1):
    tf.keras.preprocessing.image.save_img(f'my_picture_{i}.png', image)
```

[image]